# Accesing variable declared in the main function inside enclosing function and than return it back from main function

Tags: java, android

Scenario is very simple I have array `pArray` which is declared in the main function because it has to return it so must have access to ti but that array gets populated inside a listener function.

I cant initialize it inside that function because its not `final` and if I mark it final I cant edit to it.

I tried returning something out of `success` function by changing its return type from void to `String[][]` but that’s not allowed.

Question is can I return something from listener function to have access to it inside main function and if yes hwo will I get access to returned object?

```
private String[][] GetGooglePlaces(List<NameValuePair>[] nameValuePairs) {
    String[][] pArray = null;
        try {   
            iGPlaceApi.getStreams(itemsPerPage, pageNumber * itemsPerPage, new Callback<mGooglePlacesApiResponse>() {

                @Override
                public void failure(RetrofitError retrofitError) {
                    //TODO
                }

                @Override
                public void success(mGooglePlacesApiResponse obj, Response arg1) {
                    pArray = new String[obj.results.size()][4];
                    for (int i = 0; i < obj.results.size(); i++) {
                        mGooglePlaces.place place = obj.results.get(i);
                        pArray[i][0] = place.icon;
                        pArray[i][1] = place.name;

                    }

                }
            });
        return pArray;
    }
```

I don't want to declare `pArray` as global var of field as it doesn't really have any purpose outside this function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

getStreams probably spawns another thread, that is why you attach a callback.

It will spawn another thread because it wants to do a long running operation, so that 1 it does not hang the main thread & 2 you can give some other feedback to your user until it returns you the answer (in its callback).

So really you shouldn't have a return value from this method, you should listen for the callback and respond appropriately. ***Saying that you can hack it***:

```
private String[][] GetGooglePlaces(List<NameValuePair>[] nameValuePairs) {
    String[][] pArray = null;

        CountDownLatch countDownLatch = new CountDownLatch(1); // Set up a latch 

        try {   
            iGPlaceApi.getStreams(itemsPerPage, pageNumber * itemsPerPage, new Callback<mGooglePlacesApiResponse>() {

                @Override
                public void failure(RetrofitError retrofitError) {
                    //TODO
                }

                @Override
                public void success(mGooglePlacesApiResponse obj, Response arg1) {
                    pArray = new String[obj.results.size()][4];
                    for (int i = 0; i < obj.results.size(); i++) {
                        mGooglePlaces.place place = obj.results.get(i);
                        pArray[i][0] = place.icon;
                        pArray[i][1] = place.name;

                    }
                    countDownLatch.countDown(); // unlock the latch when you get your callback
                }
            });

        try {
            countDownLatch.await(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS);  // make it wait before you return
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }

        return pArray;
    }
```

**note** if you run this on your main thread, you'll crash your app with an ANR

---

What you should really do is deal with this ASyncronously

```
private void getGooglePlaces(GooglePlacesListener finishedListener) {
        try {   
            iGPlaceApi.getStreams(itemsPerPage, pageNumber * itemsPerPage, new Callback<GooglePlacesApiResponse>() {

                @Override
                public void failure(RetrofitError retrofitError) {
                    finishedListener.onFailure();
                }

                @Override
                public void success(mGooglePlacesApiResponse obj, Response arg1) {
                    String[][] pArray = new String[obj.results.size()][4];
                    for (int i = 0; i < obj.results.size(); i++) {
                        mGooglePlaces.place place = obj.results.get(i);
                        pArray[i][0] = place.icon;
                        pArray[i][1] = place.name;

                    }
                    finishedListener.onRetrieved(pArray);
                }
            });
    }

  public interface GooglePlacesListener {
       void onRetrieved(String[][] places);
       void onFailure();
  }
```